# Single check box click selects all check boxes in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In jquery mobile,I have created a separate page for products. It is loaded dynamically from query Local Sq-lite Database with phonegap. This below coding works fine and Display List of Products with check box. But if i click one check box, all check boxes are selected. Also some native check boxes are displayed on screen. How to display this check box list properly and get checked check box value on submit?

```
$('#productspage').live('pageinit',function(event){
    loadProducts();
});

// Load Products for Products page
function loadProducts()
{
    var db=window.openDatabase("salesorder", "1.0", "SalesOrder", 1048576);
    if(db!=null)
    {
        db.transaction(queryProductsTable, errorPT);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("table not exists");
    }
}


function queryProductsTable(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM products', [], queryProductsSuccess, errorPT);
}

function errorPT(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

//Query products and append to products_list
function queryProductsSuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    $("#products_list").empty();
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
           var product_id=results.rows.item(i).productid; // Returns null
           var product_name=results.rows.item(i).productname;
           var product_price=results.rows.item(i).unit_price;
           var product_stock=results.rows.item(i).qtyinstock;
           $("#products_list").append("<input type='checkbox' name='products_check' id='"+product_id+"' value='"+product_name+"' price='"+product_price+"' stock='"+product_stock+"'  class='custom'><label for='"+product_id+"'>"+product_name+"</label>");
      }
      $("#products_list").trigger("create");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave every checkbox the same name. Append the row number to the name so you get a unique name.

Comment: I modified unique id to each check box,but not works.I seen a unwanted  native check box display on screen.All check boxes works depends on this native check box.

Comment: I solved this problem...In queryProductsSuccess(tx, results) function product id return "null". So this Check box are not render properly also not able to select. After make changes in product id issue, It works fine.